# Google App Scripts / TwitterLib getting error Exception when trying to post a tweet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, twitter

Trying to implement TwitterLib to send tweets from Google Sheets. I am using Google App Scripts, and the following code -

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('View');
var startRowNumber = 1;
var endRowNumber = sheet.getLastRow();

function sendTweets() {
  var twitterKeys = {
      TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  }
  
  var props = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  props.setProperties(twitterKeys);
  var params = new Array(0);
  var service = new Twitterlib.OAuth(props);

  var quote;
  var identifier;
  
  for (var currentRowNumber = startRowNumber; currentRowNumber <= endRowNumber; currentRowNumber++) {
        var row = sheet.getRange(currentRowNumber + ":" + currentRowNumber).getValues();
        // check that the second column (Date) is equal to today
        if (isToday(row[0][1])) {
            quote = row[0][0];
            identifier = currentRowNumber - 1;
          if (!service.hasAccess()) {
            console.log("Authentication Failed");
          } else {
            console.log("Authentication Successful");      
            var status = quote + "\n\n" + "#Quotes #Motivation";
            try {
              var response = service.sendTweet(status, params);
              console.log(response);
            } catch (e) {   console.log(e)  }
          }
          break;
        }
    } 
  
}

function isToday(date) {
    var today = new Date();
    var dateFromRow = new Date(date);
    return dateFromRow.getDate() == today.getDate() &&
        dateFromRow.getMonth() == today.getMonth() &&
        dateFromRow.getFullYear() == today.getFullYear()
}
```

I have signed up for Twitter DEV and have my API Key and Secret (CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET above) and Access Token and Access Secret as well. I have turned on OAuth 1.0a, Read and write and Direct Message selected, and a Callback URI of (https://script.google.com/macros/s/YOUR_SCRIPT_ID/usercallback) - Replacing YOUR_SCRIPT_ID with the actual one I have.

I am seeing an Authentication Successful message in my Console, but seeing this error when running inside Apps Scripts IDE:

```
Send tweet failure. Error was: {"name":"Exception"}
```

Nothing more. I am not sure what else to check to see what I am doing wrong. Any help or resources to read over would greatly be appreciated! Thank you so much!

JJ

Comment: Does your app have Essential Access, or Elevated Access? You will need elevated access to use the V1.1 API which is probably what the Google Script is using.